# CodeIgniter Rest API + Facebook SDK

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, rest, facebook-graph-api

I use Phil Sturgeon's Rest API (https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver) in my CodeIgniter setup.

My API uses the Facebook SDK to interact with Facebook's Graph API, requesting information about the user, and so on. However, when I make an AJAX call to my API, I get an empty Facebook object as return.

I did some checks and it appears that Facebook's $_REQUEST['code'] and $_REQUEST['state'] (for CSRF protection) are not provided when I make this call via Phil Sturgeon's Rest API.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Add code. Hard to tell without seeing it, but guessing Fb is sending the request to an api function which has the wrong http method. i.e. if your function is `fb_post()` and the callback url is the same, and the callback is a `GET` request, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it (finally)!

Discovered it was **$facebook->getUser()** returning 0. Needed to set **cookie = true** in both the PHP SDK & JS SDK.